# how to pull in sendgrid json with jquery getJSON()

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to get statistics from sendgrid by using getJSON().  Their JSON feed reads:

```
[{"date":"2009-06-20",
"requests":12342,
"bounces":12,
"clicks":10223,
"opens":9992,
"spamreports":5,
"unique_clicks":3,
"unique_opens":6,
"blocked":7},

{"date":"2009-06-21",
"requests":32342,
"bounces":10,
"clicks":14323,
"opens":10995,
"spamreports":7,
"unique_clicks":3,
"unique_opens":9,
"blocked":4},

{"date":"2009-06-22",
"requests":52342,
"bounces":11,
"clicks":19223,
"opens":12992,
"spamreports":2,
"unique_clicks":5,
"unique_opens":2,
"blocked":8}]
```

This is the jquery code to render it into the browser, but nothing is showing up?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var stats = "https://sendgrid.com/api/stats.get.json?api_user=youremail@domain.com&api_key=secureSecret&days=2"

    $.getJSON(stats, function(key, value) {
                $('', {
                    id : 'sg_stats',
                    html : ' ' + key + '' + value ''
                }).appendto('body');
    }); 
});
```

I'm using this in Rails 3.  I tested a flickr feed and that worked, so jQuery runs in rails.

Do I need a success function on the getJSON() call?

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON()` does not provide those arguments in the callback.

Instead, wrap it with `$.each()`.

Comment: like this: $.each(stats, function(key, value) {
            $('<ul>', {
                id : 'sg_stats',
                html : '<li> ' + key + '</li><li>' + value '</li>'
            }).appendto('body');)